# Converting data to a 2 column format?

Tags: r

If I have a dataset like the following:

```
LA NY MA
1   2 3
4   5 6
3   5
    4
```

(In other words, each row has a different structure.  LA has 3 values, NY has 4 values, etc.)
I am trying to use `lm` to perform an ANOVA test (to decide whether the mean number is the same in each state), and it keeps showing "an error occurred" because rows do not match. One idea I got was to convert data to a 2-column format. Which command/package should I use to perform that task?

Edit: the data is from the txt file.

Comment: How do you have the data saved? It seems like you already have imported the data into R before you got an error from `lm()`. Please include in your question the structure of your data (by including the output from `str(data)`.

Comment: something like `na.omit(reshape2::melt(yourdata))`.  What are the results of `str()` on your data?

Comment: Try `read.table(file, fill=TRUE, header=TRUE)` when you read in the data

Comment: @BenBolker, `melt` has an `na.rm` argument, so you shouldn't need `na.omit`.

Comment: Output of str(data) and head(data) will help greatly. The OP should post it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option after you read the file to convert to a 2-column format would be

```
df <- read.table("Betty.txt", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, sep="\t") 
## (as @Richard Scriven mentioned in the comment)
na.omit(stack(df))
#    values ind
#1       1  LA
#2       4  LA
#3       3  LA
#5       2  NY
#6       5  NY
#7       5  NY
#8       4  NY
#9       3  MA
#10      6  MA
```

#### Update

The above I got by transforming the data to have `\t` delimiter.  But, if the file is copy/pasted directly from the OP's post without any change (making sure that there are spaces for the 3rd and 4th row after the 2nd column)

```
 lines <- readLines('Betty1.txt')
 lines2 <-  gsub("(?<=[^ ]) +|^[ ]+(?<=[ ])(?=[^ ])", ",", lines, perl=TRUE)

 lines2
 #[1] "LA,NY,MA" "1,2,3"    "4,5,6"    "3,5,"     ",4,"    
 df1 <- read.table(text=lines2, sep=',', header=TRUE)
 df1
 # LA NY MA
 #1  1  2  3
 #2  4  5  6
 #3  3  5 NA
 #4 NA  4 NA
```

and then do

```
 na.omit(stack(df1))
```

#### Update2

Another option if you have fixed width columns is to use `read.fwf`

```
 df <- read.fwf('Betty1.txt', widths=c(3,3,3), skip=1)
 colnames(df) <- scan('Betty1.txt', nlines=1, what="", quiet=TRUE)
 df
 #  LA NY MA
 #1  1  2  3
 #2  4  5  6
 #3  3  5 NA
 #4 NA  4 NA

 library(tidyr)
 gather(df, Var, Val, LA:MA, na.rm=TRUE)
 #  Var Val
 #1  LA   1
 #2  LA   4
 #3  LA   3
 #4  NY   2
 #5  NY   5
 #6  NY   5
 #7  NY   4
 #8  MA   3
 #9  MA   6
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be correct. The second "4" should be under "NY", not under "LA".

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks, I must have read it with `4` in the first column.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto I tried with a `\t` delimiter and it now works, but based on the data showed, it is not clear whether the example was copy/pasted from a .txt or excel dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an 'NA' to the 4th line of your text and try:

```
> ddf = read.table(text="
+ LA NY MA
+ 1   2 3
+ 4   5 6
+ 3   5
+ NA  4    
+ ", header=T, fill=T)
> 
> ddf
  LA NY MA
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  3  5 NA
4 NA  4 NA
> 
> dput(ddf)
structure(list(LA = c(1L, 4L, 3L, NA), NY = c(2L, 5L, 5L, 4L), 
    MA = c(3L, 6L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("LA", "NY", "MA"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
> 
> mm = melt(ddf)
No id variables; using all as measure variables
> 
> mm
   variable value
1        LA     1
2        LA     4
3        LA     3
4        LA    NA
5        NY     2
6        NY     5
7        NY     5
8        NY     4
9        MA     3
10       MA     6
11       MA    NA
12       MA    NA
> 
> with(mm, aov(value~variable))
Call:
   aov(formula = value ~ variable)

Terms:
                 variable Residuals
Sum of Squares   4.833333 15.166667
Deg. of Freedom         2         6

Residual standard error: 1.589899
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
3 observations deleted due to missingness
```